# how update attribute from json file in nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

how to put field values ​​from json file into attribute nifi

Json file:
{
"_id" : "eCT9agQkchqPnyDgd"
}

i used updateAttribute not work: $._id, {$._id}

Comment: use EvaluateJsonPath processor: https://nifi.apache.org/documentation/nifi-2.0.0-M1/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/2.0.0-M1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html

Answer (score 0):

use EvaluateJsonPath processor:

https://nifi.apache.org/documentation/nifi-2.0.0-M1/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/2.0.0-M1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html

in your case add a new property for a processor with name `id` and expression `$.id`